# How to select DOM ID with data-attr in css?

Tags: css, html, dom

I have a html page

```
 <smalltooltip id="menu-discussion" data-title-tooltip="Discussion"></smalltooltip>
 <smalltooltip id="menu-settings" data-title-tooltip="Settings"></smalltooltip>
```

and css style

```
smalltooltip[data-title-tooltip]:after {
//css style
}
```

It's working, but how to select id "menu-discussion" like this:

```
#menu-discussion[data-title-tooltip]:after{
    width: 70px;
}
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just that you are selecting the 'data-title-tooltip' attribute instead of just 'data-title'?

```
#menu-discussion[data-title]:after {...}
```

or are you missing the content property for the after pseudo element?

```
#menu-discussion[data-title]:after {
  content: '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following style

```
smalltooltip[id="menu-discussion"][data-title-tooltip]:after {
     width: 70px;
}
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/IJPhnQ6rq6Yi5I2yYJuu?p=preview

**Edit**

As per the edited question, there should be no issue with the style specified, however, I will recommend you to have style like above specifying the element, as unqualified attribute selectors are known to be slow

Comment: @MinhAnh - I have updated the answer. Please re-check.